# Error writing to Hive table with HCatStorer()

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, hcatalog

I'm currently pulling data from a hive table over S3 with HCatLoader(), and attempting to write back out to a hive table over S3 with HCatStorer().  I'm using the default Hive install that comes baked into AWS EMR.

HCatLoader works fine, and I can dump data correctly in script (DUMP B below works fine).

```
register '/home/hadoop/pig/lib/*.jar';
register '/home/hadoop/pig/*.jar';


A = LOAD '$db_name.$hive_table' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();

PARTITION_FILTER = FILTER A BY date=='$dateVar' AND hour=='$hourVar';

B = LIMIT PARTITION_FILTER 10;

--DUMP B;

STORE B INTO '$output_db.$output_table' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

I can also write the data out fine to S3 bucket using PigStorage with hive table delimiter and then add the partition via hive script - but we need to utilize HCatalog dynamic partitioning.

I'm getting errors implying the connection is refused to due to inability to connect to any metastore URI's provided.  My understanding is that HcatLoader() and HCatStorer() use the same hive-site.xml file, though - and I only get the error when I include HCatStorer().

Metastore URI parameter in hive-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>hive.metastore.uris</name>
    <value>thrift://localhost:9083</value>
</property>
```

Here is log from job tracker:

```
Job commit failed: java.io.IOException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.commitJob(PigOutputCommitter.java:281)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobCommit(CommitterEventHandler.java:253)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:216)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.commitJob(PigOutputCommitter.java:279)
... 5 more
Caused by: org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatException : 2006 : Error adding partition to metastore. Cause : MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:336)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:214)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:154)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveClientCache.java:246)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:170)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:167)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4767)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4764)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.getOrCreate(HiveClientCache.java:167)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:143)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveClient(HCatUtil.java:548)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.registerPartitions(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:616)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.commitJob(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:206)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.commitJob(PigOutputCommitter.java:279)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobCommit(CommitterEventHandler.java:253)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:216)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
... 28 more
)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.registerPartitions(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:704)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.commitJob(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:206)
... 10 more
Caused by: MetaException(message:Could not connect to meta store using any of the URIs provided. Most recent failure: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:185)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:336)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:214)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:154)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveClientCache.java:246)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:170)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:167)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4767)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4764)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.getOrCreate(HiveClientCache.java:167)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:143)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveClient(HCatUtil.java:548)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.registerPartitions(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:616)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.commitJob(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:206)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.mapReduceLayer.PigOutputCommitter.commitJob(PigOutputCommitter.java:279)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.handleJobCommit(CommitterEventHandler.java:253)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.commit.CommitterEventHandler$EventProcessor.run(CommitterEventHandler.java:216)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:180)
... 28 more
)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:382)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:214)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:154)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$CacheableHiveMetaStoreClient.(HiveClientCache.java:246)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:170)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache$4.call(HiveClientCache.java:167)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache$1.load(LocalCache.java:4767)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4764)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.getOrCreate(HiveClientCache.java:167)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HiveClientCache.get(HiveClientCache.java:143)
at org.apache.hcatalog.common.HCatUtil.getHiveClient(HCatUtil.java:548)
at org.apache.hcatalog.mapreduce.FileOutputCommitterContainer.registerPartitions(FileOutputCommitterContainer.java:616)
```

Any insight is greatly appreciated.  This has had me stumped for quite a while.  I've seen a lot of old jira tickets open on issues that sound similar, but they're from ~2012.

Comment: Wanted to come back and respond to this with the answer.  There was a pig-opt set in .bashrc to run with metastore.uri of localhost on 9083.